# How to override CSS styles of Bootstrap for ".navlink"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to change the color of the ".navlink" to white in my html file.
Please help me to change the color of the ".navlink" to white.

```html
<section id="navbar-section">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-primary " >
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">tent workshop</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item active" >
                   <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item active" >
                   <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Contact</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item active" >
                   <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Products</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>

   </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: `.nav-link { color: white; }`

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the selectors that Bootstrap uses to be able to override the color defined by bootstrap. Also, your CSS must be included after Bootstrap.

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, 
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

OR you override the CSS from Bootstrap by using "!important"

```css
.nav-link {
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.nav-link:focus, 
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define it in the class name of the element:

```
 <a href="#" class="nav-link link-light" aria-current="page">Home</a>
```

**usage:**

- link-light
- link-dark
- link-primary
- link-success

Answer (score -1):

would you try this?

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link" style="color:white;" aria-current="page">Home</a>
```

style="color:white;" it usually works

Comment: thanks it woeks

Comment: Inline styles are no good solution. An inline style loses many of the advantages of a style sheet by mixing content with presentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-light " >
```

Try this . It will make your navigation bar background color to white